# Remove all generated HTML for blocks/regions

Tags: theming, blocks

Even though I've overriden the block.html.twig template, as well as region.html.twig, Drupal still outputs a lot of hardcoded HTML in my templates, for Block Regions (from Layouts) for example.

#### block.html.twig

```
{% set attributes = attributes.addClass([
  'block-' ~ configuration.provider|clean_class,
  attributes.id
]) %}
```

#### region.html.twig

```
{% if content %}
    {{ content }}
{% endif %}
```

What am I missing? Why do I keep seeing all this markup?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you referring to the comments (green blocks)?

Comment: well I don't mind the comments of course:) I'm referring to the actual HTML divs inserted by Drupal.